# Problem build Android support 64-bit crash C++

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, 64-bit, 32-bit

I'm getting problem when update Android project build support 64-bit. 
I have a lib C++, when build armeabi-v7a: not problem. But, when I using arm64-v8a to build lib, when game running getting crash.

```cpp
uint32 x;
// dosomething x 
x++;
switch(*(uint8 *)x) // crash here
```

Comment: `x` is not a pointer, so why are you applying a `(uint8 *)` pointer cast?  There is a lot of context missing from the code you posted.

Comment: Try to declare **`x`** as `uint8 *`.  I believe that this may be easier to fix.